# SSIS web service task timeout value

Tags: web-services, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to call a long running web service from **WebServiceTask**  in SSIS, but the **TimeOut value** for it seems to be a max of 300 seconds or 5 mins. But i am afraid that it might get timed out.

is there a way to increase the timeout vale

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately no. The Web Service Task, as I see it, is one of those "after thoughts." It satisfies a check box but doesn't go beyond the surface of functionality. I have found that I have a better web service experience if I just use a script component.